# How to get ribbon control in MFC feature pack to process ID_WINDOW_TILE_VERT

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I'm porting an older MFC application to use MFC feature pack with ribbon UI and have found the ribbon UI doesn't process MDI windows tiling commands such ID_WINDOW_TILE_VERT.  Is there a way to enable this functionality?

Single stepping through the MFC source I get as far as the following in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\winmdi.cpp*, which seems correct;

```
BOOL CMDIFrameWnd::OnMDIWindowCmd(UINT nID)
{
    ASSERT(m_hWndMDIClient != NULL);

    UINT msg;
    UINT wParam = 0;
    switch (nID)
    {
    default:
        return FALSE;       // not for us
    case ID_WINDOW_ARRANGE:
        msg = WM_MDIICONARRANGE;
        break;
    case ID_WINDOW_CASCADE:
        msg = WM_MDICASCADE;
        break;
    case ID_WINDOW_TILE_HORZ:
        wParam = MDITILE_HORIZONTAL;
        // fall through
    case ID_WINDOW_TILE_VERT:
        ASSERT(MDITILE_VERTICAL == 0);
        msg = WM_MDITILE;
        break;
    }

    ::SendMessage(m_hWndMDIClient, msg, wParam, 0);
    return TRUE;
}
```

I have also tried calling

```
MDITile(MDITILE_HORIZONTAL);
```

directly, which essentially does the same thing and does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some experimentation, when the MFC mdi interface is based on **CMDIFrameWndEx** frames hosting dockable panes based **CMDIChildWndEx** and tabbed documents are enabled, floating windows are not available and hence neither are tiling or cascading.

To enable tiling, simply remove the line

```
EnableMDITabbedGroups(TRUE, mdiTabParams);
```

from your CMainFrame::OnCreate method.  The downside is you also lose your nice tabbed document UI.  FWIW, I also tried calling **EnableDocking(CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI)** after enabling tabbed groups, but it does not make any difference.  Also under discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/025f5777-3e7e-499e-8cac-eccd4e645e0f/how-to-get-ribbon-control-in-mfc-feature-pack-to-process-idwindowtilevert?forum=vcgeneral)

**Update:**  In order to keep the tabbed interface and split the screens, the following alternative works well to split a single horizontal view with multiple tabs into two views, with current tab in the new view.

```
void SplitViews(CMDIFrameWndEx *pFrame) 
{   
    pFrame->MDITabNewGroup();
    pFrame->MDITabMoveToNextGroup(); 
}
```